# Legend color of highcharter boxplot in R

Tags: r, highcharts

I tried to build boxplot as described here https://rpubs.com/techanswers88/highcharter-boxplot-in-r

```
install.packages("highcharter")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("gapminder")

library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

ds <- gapminder %>%
   dplyr::filter(year == 2007) %>%
   dplyr::arrange(-pop)

myboxplotData <- data_to_boxplot(
    ds,
    lifeExp,
    continent,
    group_var     = continent,
    add_outliers  = FALSE,
    fillColor     = c("red", "green","yellow", "pink","blue"),
    color        = "black",                        
   )

highchart()%>%
hc_xAxis(type ="category") %>%
hc_add_series_list(myboxplotData) %>%
hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "contient")) %>%
hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Life expectancy")) %>%
hc_title(text= "Boxplot  using highcharter") %>% 
hc_subtitle(text= "Life expectancy of each continent") %>% 
hc_caption(text= "Based on year 2007 population") %>% 
hc_legend(enabled= FALSE)
```

and its working fine

Now I wanted to add a legend at the bottom so I changed

```
hc_legend(enabled= FALSE)
```

to

```
hc_legend(enabled= TRUE)
```

The name of the legends appears but all colors are black instead of those defined in fillColor in the `data_to_boxplot` function.

So I tried :

```
color = c("red", "green","yellow", "pink","blue")
```

instead of

```
color        = "black"
```

and it works for legend color BUT the boxplot shape and the median disappears (not black anymore)

Is there a way to keep the shape of boxplot and median black and the legens with the same color as the boxplot fillColor ? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highcharter, the `color` argument actually changes the color of the boxplot outline and median. You're correct in using the `fillColor` argument to change the color of the boxplot itself, but unfortunately, the Highcharter library in R does not automatically use `fillColor` for the legend symbols.

One solution to this issue is to change the color of the legend symbols using JavaScript directly within the `hc_chart` function using the `Highcharts.setOptions` method. Here is how you can do it:

```
install.packages("highcharter")
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("gapminder")

library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

ds <- gapminder %>%
  dplyr::filter(year == 2007) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(-pop)

myboxplotData <- data_to_boxplot(
  ds,
  lifeExp,
  continent,
  group_var     = continent,
  add_outliers  = FALSE,
  fillColor     = c("red", "green","yellow", "pink","blue"),
  color        = "black",                        
)

highchart()%>%
  hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function () {
        Highcharts.each(this.series, function (series) {
          series.legendSymbol.attr({ fill: series.options.fillColor });
        });
      }")
    )
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type ="category") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(myboxplotData) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "contient")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Life expectancy")) %>%
  hc_title(text= "Boxplot  using highcharter") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text= "Life expectancy of each continent") %>% 
  hc_caption(text= "Based on year 2007 population") %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled= TRUE)
```